# How to protect against USB malware?

Tags: usb

What measures should I take to avoid any infection through USB devices?

For example, there is a tiny virus called shortcut which hides your files and put shortcuts instead. I was wondering if there are some special measures besides the traditional ones (updated antivirus, firewall...)? Should we disable them and enable on demand or set privileges on them, what do you propose?

Comment: Could you clarify if you mean USB Drives like a flash drive / external hard drive? USB Devices is very broad. Also, is this for home use on a personal network or for a business? You would go to more extremes in a business environment because end users are a big liability.

Comment: i mean any USB device

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any infection you should remove the USB ports.

Here are some measures one might take to minimise the probability of an infection:

1.) Provide users with USB devices. Allow only those devices to be used.

2.) Disable autorun for USB devices.

3.) Disallow the use of U3 devices.

4.) Allow only specially trained users with the permissions to transfer files between USB devices and your network. Those should know the procedures to minimise the probability of transferring infected files to your network (e.g. scanning the files beforehand).

5.) Allow the use of USB devices only on specific, air-gaped computers. Check files for malware before transferring them to your network.